# Load data.table in QuantMod & Quantstrat

Tags: r, quantmod, quantstrat

I have a `data.table` with my own data prices for 3 Isins.

```
PricesDir= "C:/Downloads/Prices" #With 10 CSVs just with bid-ask info.
files=list.files(PricesDir, pattern="*csv",full.names = TRUE)
prices = rbindlist(lapply(files, fread, fill = TRUE), fill = TRUE) #make the data.table
```

The `data.table` looks like this:

```
dt <- data.table(
times = as.POSIXct(c("2017-06-15 12:00:00",
        "2017-06-21 12:00:00",
        "2017-08-15 12:00:00",
        "2017-08-21 12:00:00",
        "2017-06-15 12:00:00",
        "2017-06-21 12:00:00",
        "2017-08-15 12:00:00",
        "2017-08-21 12:00:00"),
        format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),

isin = c("isin1", 
       "isin1",
       "isin1",
       "isin1",
       "isin2",
       "isin2",
       "isin3",
       "isin3"),

midprice = c(101.933,
        102.121,
        98.829,
        98.533,
        112.145,
        112.348,
        104.146,
        104.343)
)

myticks<-as.xts(read.zoo(dt))

#convert data.table to "xts", "zoo"
myticks<-as.xts(read.zoo(dt))
Warning message:
In zoo(rval3, ix) : some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I want to make strategies with that info. However I don't know how to use this data in Quantstrat. All I see in the documentation is importing prices with online servers. Do I have to treat each CSV separately and convert it to OHLC, otherwise it does not work? How do I use the symbols function?

I have another `data.table` to get my signals. This data table looks like:

```
sgnl <- data.table(

date = as.POSIXct(c("2017-06-15 12:00:00",
                  "2017-06-15 12:00:00",
                  "2017-08-15 12:00:00",
                  "2017-08-15 12:00:00"),
                format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),

date2 = as.POSIXct(c("2017-06-21 12:00:00",
                  "2017-06-21 12:00:00",
                  "2017-08-21 12:00:00",
                  "2017-08-21 12:00:00"),
                format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),

isin = c("isin1", 
       "isin2",
       "isin1",
       "isin3"),

name = c("news1",
      "news1",
      "news2",
      "news2")  
)
```

With Quantstrat how do I load my dt?:

```
 symbols<- dt$isin
 getSymbols.rda(symbols,
           env,
           dir="",
           return.class = "xts",
           extension="rda",
           col.names=c("times","isin","midprice"),
           sep=",")
```

Comment: Yes you can run quantstrat on tick data, provided each symbol has 'bid' and 'ask' as column names.  You could create your own indicators for the tick data 'externally' (don't use add.indicator) to start with, which might be easier .... and use `add.signal` and `add.rule` as you would normally.  You aren't forced to convert to OHLC data.  Can you provide some reproducible tick data (make some fake data or a link to a small data set?) and show what you've tried so far wih quantstrat?

Comment: @FXQuantTrade many thanks for your help! I have provided a little example of what I have as data. The thing is that I don't really know how to load my data.table into Quantstrat.

Comment: What is your question?  all your symbol data in quantstrat must be xts objects.  You can just load them in your global environment, with the name of the object equal to the name of the symbol.  e.g. `AAPL` is the name of the object containing apple bid/ask or OHLC data.  You can load your data from any source... just a plain text file `with fread`, which you convert to an xts object.   You don't need to use getSymbols to load your market data into your global environment.  You're complicating the problem.  Just convert your datatable to an xts object in a market data format that makes sense.

Comment: @FXQuantTrader many thanks! I am quite new with Quanstart. Should I make an xts object for each ISIN, instead of having them together in one data.table which I convert to xts?

Comment: Absolutely.  each xts object should contain the data for one symbol.  Just load these data objects into the global environment and follow like in the quantstrat examples and you should have no problem